# ImageURL stored in FireBase storage isn't stored in the FireBase database

Tags: ios, swift

now i'm trying to setting up a signUpEvent using firebase.

in this app, it is available to register images. and i'm using images from firebase for another mainviewclass.

but imageUrl stored in Firebase Storage isn't stored into Firebase database.

what should i do to solve this problem?

this is sourcecode about signup.

```
@objc func signupEvent(){

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { (user, err) in

            let uid = user?.user.uid

            let image = self.imageView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)


            Storage.storage().reference().child("userImages").child(uid!).putData(image!, metadata: nil, completion: { (data, error) in



//this is problem

                let imageUrl = 
data?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in



                let urlText = url?.absoluteString
                let values = ["userName":self.name.text!,"profileImageUrl":urlText!, "uid":Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid as Any]

                    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                        if(err==nil){
                            self.cancelEvent()
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
Database.database().reference().child(uid!).setValue(["name":self.name.text!])
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Storage.storage().reference().child("userImages").child(uid!).downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                //asing the url to your user in DB.
            })
```